# Detecting (hollow) rectangles in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, blob, detection

I'm trying to read an image that (might, depending on circumstances) look like this

[image]

i want to be able to get the bounding rects, corners, and center of the two rectangle in a fashion similar to this

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://cvblob.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/Images/test_screenshot.png))</sub>

(taken from the cvBlob website)

I haven't foun anything that works. I tried the squares.cpp sample, but it keeps crashing whenever I run it. I can't find any other code that will work for this. (I would use cvBlob, but it has 0 documentation)

Comment: The simplest way to obtain a bounding box of a blob is Region Grow Segmentation algorithm.

Comment: Im sorry, can you elaborate? i cant find any links/samples explaining it..

Comment: I can elaborate more, when you elaborate more on your question. Please share what have you tried, don't ask for a complete solution. Did you at least try google? :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing